# Mono can't find System.Data.dll on Linux

Tags: c#, sqlite, mono, system.data

I'm trying to compile the following example from [here](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/dataset/) with dmcs (and gmcs... I tried both):

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;

public class Example
{

    static void Main() 
    {
        string cs = "URI=file:test.db";

        using( SqliteConnection con = new SqliteConnection(cs))
        {

            con.Open();

            DataTable table = new DataTable("Friends2");

            DataColumn column;
            DataRow row;

            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
            column.ColumnName = "Id";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            column = new DataColumn();
            column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
            column.ColumnName = "Name";
            table.Columns.Add(column);

            row = table.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = 1;
            row["Name"] = "Jane";
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            row = table.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = 2;
            row["Name"] = "Lucy";
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            row = table.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = 3;
            row["Name"] = "Thomas";
            table.Rows.Add(row);

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Friends2";

            using (SqliteDataAdapter da = new SqliteDataAdapter(sql, con))
            {
                using (new SqliteCommandBuilder(da))
                {
                    da.Fill(table);
                    da.Update(table);
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the following CL args to try and get it to compile:

```
dmcs sqlite8.cs -r:Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll, System.Data.dll
gmcs sqlite8.cs -r:Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll, System.Data.dll
```

And the following errors manifest themselves:

```
sqlite8.cs(2,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace 'Data' does not exists in the namespace 'System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

or

```
error CS2001: Source file 'System.Data.dll' could not be found
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

So Mono can't find the System.Data reference. What do I do to fix this? I'm used to doing C#, but CLI Mono compilation is new to me.

Comment: Upvoted. If you're going to downvote, dear Reader, please explain why. This is a perfectly understandable question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass multiple assemblies using a single `-r` option, you'll have to provide `-r` for each reference, such as:

```
mcs sqlite8.cs -r:Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll -r:System.Data.dll
```

Notice that the error mentions "source file".

Comment: Winner winner, chicken dinner. Thanks!

Comment: You can pass multiple assemblies. However, you cannot have white space after the comma separator.

Comment: Thanks to Jester for the answer.